# Vuejs Apollo I have a problem to retrieve an id in array

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

I am using a mutation with apollo and Vuejs to remove an entry for an event from my calendar. I need to retrieve the event id in an array.

```js
    deleteEvent: function () {
      this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          mutation: MUTATION_entreePlanningDelete,
          variable: {
            id: this.id,
          },
        })

        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    },
```

in this function I appeal to the mutation request.

[image]

here is my array (this name : evenements), we can see the id. Can you tell me how to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem

I did not pay attention, we just had to put in the event = parameter to the event selected in the calendar to add .id to say to retrieve the event id.

```
           here is what had to be done on the template side

  <v-btn text @click="deleteEvent(selectedEvent)"> Effacer </v-btn>


          and here is what had to be done in the delete function



deleteEvent: function (event) {

  this.$apollo
    .mutate({
      mutation: MUTATION_entreePlanningDelete,
      variables: {
        id: event.id,
      },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: QUERY_entreesPlanning }]
    })

    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

try these two options:

for 1st index

```
console.log(data[0].id);
```

or if it gives undefined or something else

then try to grab it from object directly

```
let { id } = data[0];
console.log(id);
```

also try without the index

Answer (score 0):

I have test this option:

console.log(evenements[0].id);

I get the id , i have test your second option

let { idEvent } = evenements[0].id;
console.log(idEvent);

idEvent is undefined but in this version it's ok

let idEvent = evenements[0].id;
console.log(idEvent);

[image]

evenements it's an array but impossible to recover its value elsewhere